# Rasa: Error in 'Building a Simple Bot'

Tags: rasa-core

I am following the tutorial: https://core.rasa.com/tutorial_basics.html#tutorial-basics
and I am in the step:
Let’s run

```
python -m rasa_nlu.train -c nlu_model_config.json --fixed_model_name current
```

And I am having this error:

```
usage: train.py [-h] [-o PATH] (-d DATA | -u URL) -c CONFIG [-t NUM_THREADS]
                [--project PROJECT] [--fixed_model_name FIXED_MODEL_NAME]
                [--storage STORAGE] [--debug] [-v]
train.py: error: one of the arguments -d/--data -u/--url is required
```

I've try the obvious and run:

```
python -m rasa_nlu.train -c nlu_model_config.json --fixed_model_name current -d
```

But then it gives me the error:
train.py: error: argument -d/--data: expected one argument

I am really confused, since I am still running the tutorial and I don't understand what this arguments are.

Answer (score 1):

You must supply a path to the dataset after the -d flag, like this for instance

`python -m rasa_nlu.train -c nlu_model_config.json --fixed_model_name current -d data/nlu_data.md`